# How does python module import work with __init__.py when a child class needs its abstract parent class

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to figure out how to use the `__init__.py` to import two classes from a subfolder. I have an abstract parent class in one file and a child class in another file. As far as I know, the child class needs to import the parent class so you can define its parent

```
import parent

class child(parent):
    pass
```

The issue is that when I try to import the child class, I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parent'`

The file structure is:

```
project - main.py
          folder - parent.py
                   child.py
                   __init__.py
```

I have tried to get around this by importing the files in the `__init__.py` file

```
from .parent import *
from .child import *
```

as well as

```
import parent
import child
```

I still see the module error in the `child.py`. If I try to remove the import in the `child.py` then I get an error where I can't use the abstract functions from `parent.py`.

I can't figure out how it is supposed to work, or if using modules is even the correct way of doing what I want.

I have tried a few different variations in `main.py`

```
import folder

def main():
   test = folder.child.child()
```

as well as things like

```
from folder import *

def main(): ...
```

For that one, I added the line `__all__ = ["child","parent"]` to the init file

Comment: How do you start these modules? If you run `python3 main.py` and `main.py` imports `folder`, then the relative import `from .parent import *` should work.

Comment: My gosh, I forget the main code, sorry! I have tried a few different imports, mostly variations of import folder, like you said. I have also tried from folder import * and adding \_\_all__ = ["parent","child"] to the init file. I will edit my question to include that. What you are suggesting didn't work though

Comment: You don't import classes, you import modules. Using `class child(parent)` doesn't make sense if you did `import parent`

Comment: Doesn't `from .parent import parent` in `child.py` work?

Comment: What error are you seeing exactly? You must **always provide a [mcve]**. If you are getting an error, post the full error message including the stack trace

Comment: @Aleesia it could, but I didn't say you should do that

Comment: @mkrieger1 That does work! Can you explain why? Sorry, I am not seeing the difference between import parent and from .parent import parent (also if you can answer the question so I can give you the answer vote?)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, I am not the best coder. You said you import the module so you shouldn't use class child(parent). The child class needs to see the parent class to override the abstract functions. Did you not mean import the module in the child.py?

Comment: If you `import parent ` then `parent` is a module, not a class. That is what I'm saying

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga For reference the error was

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Coding Projects\Personal\Python\Test\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import folder
  File "C:\Coding Projects\Personal\Python\Test\folder\\_\_init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .child import *
  File "C:\Coding Projects\Personal\Python\Test\folder\child.py", line 1, in <module>
    import parent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parent'

Comment: So using "import x" imports a module
using "from x import *" imports all classes and functions in the file?